# Fortran strange segmentation fault

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have some a problem with my main code, so I tried to isolate the problem.
Therefore, I have this small code :

```
MODULE Param
    IMPLICIT NONE

    integer, parameter :: dr  = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15, 307)
    integer                 :: D =3
    integer                 :: Q=10
    integer                 :: mmo=16
    integer                 :: n=2
    integer                 :: x=80
    integer                 :: y=70
    integer                 :: z=20
    integer                 :: tMax=8
END MODULE Param

module m
contains
    subroutine compute(f, r)
        USE Param,  ONLY: dr, mmo, x, y, z, n
        IMPLICIT NONE

        real    (kind=dr), intent(in)  :: f(x,y,z, 0:mmo, n)
        real    (kind=dr), intent(out) :: r(x, y, z, n)
        real    (kind=dr)  :: fGlob(x,y,z, 0:mmo)
        !-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        print*, 'We are in compute subroutine'

        r= 00.0

        fGlob=sum(f,dim=5)
        r=sum(f, dim=4)

        print*, 'fGlob=', fGlob(1,1,1, 1)
        print*, 'f=', f(1,1,1, 0,1)
        print*, 'r=', r(1,1,1, 1)
    end subroutine compute
end module m


PROGRAM test_prog
    USE Param
    USE m
    Implicit None

    integer :: tStep
    real    (kind=dr), dimension(:,:,:, :,:), allocatable   :: f
    real    (kind=dr), dimension(:,:,:,:), allocatable   :: r
    !----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ! Initialise the parameters.
    print*, 'beginning of the test'

    ! Allocate
    allocate(f(x,y,z, 0:mmo,n))
    allocate(r(x,y,z, n))

    f=1.0_dr

    ! ---------------------------------------------------------
    !     Iteration over time
    ! ---------------------------------------------------------
    do tStep = 1, tMax
        print *, tStep
        call compute(f,r)
        f=f+1
        print *, 'tStep', tStep
    enddo

    print*, 'f=', f(1,1,1, 0,1)
    print*, 'r=', r(1,1,1, 1)

    ! Deallacation
    deallocate(f)
    deallocate(r)
    print*,  'End of the test program'
END PROGRAM test_prog
```

For now, I am not able to understand why when I compile with `ifort`, I have a `segmentation fault`, and it works when I compile with `gfortran`. And worst, when I compile with both `ifort` and `gfortran` with their `fast` options, I get again a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. And more confusing, when I also tried with both compilers to compile with `traceback` options, everything works fine.

I know that `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error usually means that I try to read or write in a wrong location (matrix indices etc...); but here with this small code, I see no mistake like this.

Does anyone can help me to understand why theses errors occur?

Comment: Read this -- https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/determining-root-cause-of-sigsegv-or-sigbus-errors -- and report back after you have checked all the issues it raises.

Comment: It is goodd to have a small mcve. Still, please try the debugging options your compilers offer `-g -fcheck=all -Wall` `-g -traceback -check -warn`.

Comment: I will continue to investigate, things in your link. But I think that the problem was a stack overflow problem. I will confirm you this. Anyway, Thanks for this useful link that I did not found when I was googling.

Comment: `fGlob` might be put on the stack by some compilers (Intel) by default indeed. Try `-heap-arrays`

Comment: @VladimirF I tried your debugging options, nothing was returned. I tried with `-heap-arrays -fast -O3`(`ifort`) and `-fno-stack-arrays -Ofast -O3`(`gfortran`), it worked. Is it ok to use `-fno-stack-arrays`? Should I put a number after `-heap-arrays` for a generic use or keep it like this? Are theses options destroying the optimisation ? I think you can you comment, with the answers/explanations to theses new questions, into a complete answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the size of the stack used by some compilers by default (`ifort`) or by some others when they optimise the compilation (`gfortran -Ofast`). Here, our writings exceed the size of the stack.

To solve this, I use the options `-heap-arrays` for `ifort` compiler and `-fno-stack-arrays` for `gfortran` compiler.